# Mule ForEach Unable to get first value

Tags: foreach, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have a for each loop in my Mule 3 flow.

[image]

The Collection for the same is a flow variable array as shown below:

```
"[
  "Alpha",
  "Bravo",
  "Charlie",
  "Delta",
  "Echo",
]"
```

Inside the for each, I have a session variable to store the current array value. I have set the value as #[payload]. The idea is to use each iterated ID to make an API update call. The issue is that, I am getting the complete payload as the current id session variable (as opposed to a single value). Any idea why it's not iterating 5 times (5 is the number of IDs that I have in the array).

[image]

Comment: Please add the XML of the foreach to understand the structure.

Comment: Also add the XML for when you set the `variable` processor--i.e. how you set the collection to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

i couldnt reproduce your error. may be the way your array variable is defined is not proper.  i am not sure. I did a slight change.
[image]

```
    <flow name="loos_sample" doc:id="25ef89d0-dfcd-48c3-8c66-a94373a3b46c" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="96eca53c-6976-4b0e-9a18-9fd6d0ee6520" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/loop"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="2ea9d7e3-ff1c-4ba4-99f2-40ae4c2d16e7" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="varIds" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{ arr:
[
  "Alpha",
  "Bravo",
  "Charlie",
  "Delta",
  "Echo",
]

}]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="972ee8d5-d8d6-43b6-866a-0894d1b3a450" collection="#[vars.varIds.arr]">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="4478c587-f01c-4e2a-9485-5aa4b1be11df" message="curernt item: #[payload]"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```